# Typo3 remove home page from URL

Tags: typo3

i have a website in TYPO3 Ver. 4.7.1 and I woul like to remove the homepage from URL.
http://www.mywebsite.com/home I would like be http://www.mywebsite.com/

Answer (score 4):

The only way to handle this is to add the content to the root page and add a shortcut from "Home" to the root-page.

- Root Page

  - Home -> links to root page
  - other second level pages

The only problem is that when you click on "Home", that the menu state is not triggered as "active" in typoscript HMENU/TMENU elements.

Comment: You can also do it the other way round, linking the root page with the second level page "home". Not sure if that solves the "active" issue though

Comment: But then you have the "home" in the url again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling I've done this before:

- root page

  - other first level pages

Build the menu out of two HMENUs:

1. A menu that only covers the root page level
2. A menu that covers everything else, but pretends to be one level higher up than it is in the Backend

so everything appears as a standard ul > li> ul > li menu

It's a bit quirky, but it might work

@Merec or don't you think?

Comment: Yes that one way to handle this, the other way is to use the pid of the root page (the root page is in most cases static) and check via "if", if you on the site and set the menu entry to active. I will post an example later.